# TeamCity + VSTS - Failed to perform checkout on agent target file already exists

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to configure a TeamCity build based on Visual Studio Team Services and I'm having the following error.

I can see that the files have been downloaded to the checkout directory (*C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e3b96b8eb42644db*), so I can figure out why this is happening.

```
[18:04:51]Starting the build on the agent MYAGENT
[18:04:54]Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[18:04:54]Publishing internal artifacts
[18:04:54][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[18:04:54][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[18:04:54]Using vcs information from agent file: e3b96b8eb42644db.xml
[18:04:54]Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e3b96b8eb42644db
[18:04:54]Updating sources: auto checkout (on agent) (32s)
[18:04:54][Updating sources] Will use agent side checkout
[18:04:54][Updating sources] VCS Root: tfs: https://myproject.visualstudio.com/ $/myproject Project (32s)
[18:04:54][VCS Root: tfs: https://myproject.visualstudio.com/ $/myproject Project] revision: 26497
[18:04:55][VCS Root: tfs: https://myproject.visualstudio.com/ $/myproject Project] Using java working mode
[18:04:55][VCS Root: tfs: https://myproject.visualstudio.com/ $/myproject Project] Receiving workspace (10s)
[18:05:05][Receiving workspace] Using workspace TeamCity-checkout-9755e46c9dbd4e2386cd6ff8f61f9c3f;2805f05d-0506-40bf-ace2-1cc59462cfac/MYAGENT
[18:05:05][VCS Root: tfs: https://myproject.visualstudio.com/ $/myproject Project] Updating sources to revision: 26497
[18:05:27][Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: Failed to checkout repository version 26497: com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.exceptions.VersionControlException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: renaming: target file already exists
```

Any tip?

Comment: It seems to be a modified file inside the agent repository. Like a generated file during the compilation. You might try to do a clean checkout, or go to the agent, and check if there is any pending changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After install Visual Studio the problem went away.

I've installed it because of the following information that I found in the Logs:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\tfs-agent\bin\tfs-native.exe @@C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\globalTmp\TC-TFS-595-4405_66\command.params, in file: {/CheckApi} has failed with exit code 1: No TFS assemblies were found on the system. Please make sure you have Microsoft Team Explorer installed. Supported versions: 2017 2015 2013 2012 2010 2008 2005 
[2017-01-09 17:53:25,670]   INFO - cs.tfs.TfsAgentServiceProvider - Use Java TFS SDK 
[2017-01-09 17:53:25,671]   INFO - s.tfs.TfsUpdateByCheckoutRules - Clean checkout flag was set by the build agent 
[2017-01-09 17:53:31,714]   INFO - .tfs.java.TfsJavaConsoleRunner - TFS java console command has finished: ListWorkspaces -s="https://myproject.visualstudio.com/" -u="*******" -p="*******" -inputFile=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\globalTmp\TC-TFS-595-4405_67.tmp -outputFile=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\globalTmp\TC-TFS-595-4405_68.tmp, completed in 5.998 second(s) 
[2017-01-09 17:53:31,717]   INFO - s.vcs.tfs.TfsWorkspaceProvider - Using workspace TeamCity-checkout-9ee0800418e64e77b38b598f7d5b15a5;2805f05d-0506-40bf-ace2-1cc59462cfac/MYAGENT 
[2017-01-09 17:55:21,600]   INFO - ldServer.AGENT.PollingProtocol - New command is received from server "agentFileManager
```

I believe that is related to the Java TFS SDK.
I know that install VS isn't the most elegant solution, specially for a build server. If you have any other idea, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you have modified files in your project. Thus TFS can't automatically overwrite your changed files. Try to check in pending changes or clean up the folder.